# Able to compile and run. However, when runnig the code it can not print any value which i want to print

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

template <typename T>
class Polynomial
{
private:
    Polynomial *termArray;
    //int capacity;
    //int terms;
    T coef,exp;
public:
    Polynomial()
    {   
            termArray = new Polynomial[3];
    };  
    ~Polynomial();
    void Print();
    void CreateTerm(const T coef, const int exp);
};

template <typename T>
Polynomial<T>::~Polynomial()
{
    delete []termArray;
}

template <typename T>
void Polynomial<T>::Print()
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    std::cout << termArray[i].coef << " " << termArray[i].exp << std::endl; 
}

template <typename T>
void Polynomial<T>::CreateTerm(const T coef,const int exp)
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {   
            termArray[i].coef = coef;
            termArray[i].exp = exp;
    }   
}

int main()
{
    Polynomial<double> f,g;

    f.CreateTerm(-4.8,3);
    f.CreateTerm(2.9,2);
    f.CreateTerm(-3,0);
    std::cout << "f = ";
    f.Print();

    g.CreateTerm(4.3,4);
    g.CreateTerm(-8.1,0);
    g.CreateTerm(2.2,3);

    std::cout << "g = ";
    g.Print();

return 0;
}
```

As above the topic, This code can be compiled and run. However, when runnig the code it can not print any value which i want to print out and go to long sleep.(Although i type the anything it doesn't repond to my typing)

How can i modify the code for printing.. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your constructor:

```
Polynomial()
{   
        termArray = new Polynomial[3];
};
```

When you create a new polynomial, your code then creates 3 news polynomials in the constructor. For each of these 3 polynomials, you will create 3 more! That's 13 total polynomial objects at this point. Add 3 again for the new ones. This will go on until you run out of memory. More specifically when you run out of stack space, since these are all allocated there.

Your code will never get past this line, because it will call the constructor [recursively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion):

```
termArray = new Polynomial[3];
```

Some other things to consider:

- Consider adding another class `Coefficient`.
- Instead of an array of `Polynomial` objects inside the `Polynomial` object ([quite literally your stack overflow bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)), you would have an array of `Coefficient` objects inside your `Polynomial` object.
- A polynomial can have more or less than 3 coefficients/exponents.
- If you use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of an array, you can simply call the vector's [`push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) method inside your class's `create_term()` to add a new coefficient.